# SVG animation priority during page load

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg

I have an SVG animation overlay on my website during page load. It is hidden when everything is loaded. How can I make the animation run smooth? I'd rather have a little longer loading time than have the animation stutter when the browser is allocating resources to loading the rest of the page.

```
<div id="loading-animation" style="display: block; position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: #fff; z-index: 100000">
  <img src="images/loader.svg" alt="" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; left: calc(50% - 128px); top: calc(50% - 128px); position: absolute">
</div>
```

Comment: show the code you use to hide it

Comment: show the working example jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: That might be hard to tell, as we would have to see where the culprit is in the loading of your whole page. The best is that you learn how to use your developer tools and their *Performance* panel. Then, once you'd have identified what is slowing down the rendering, you could come back here to ask about how to fix it, if you didn't figured it out yourself.

Comment: @Kaiido The page loading takes time, nothing I can do about it. The question was about how I can make sure the animation has a high priority. Everything else should be secondary to the animation.

Comment: But you are talking about performances right ? So you should avoid the background process take too much resources, and this only you can do it.